# How to write this regular expression to allow number starts with decimal without zero?

Tags: php, regex

For weight validation in PHP, I am using following regular expression that allows numbers with/wo decimal:

```
if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/", $weight))
{
    echo "Weight is not valid.";
}
```

It allows numbers in following formats:

```
5
5.55
0.55
```

But doesn't allow when entered number is:

```
.5
or
.55
```

I know this is because of the rule `/^[0-9]+`.

How can I modify above regular expression to accept number **starts directly with decimal without zero**?

**Note**

If I change `/^[0-9]+` to `/^[\.0-9]+` then the part `{1,2}` is no longer working.

Comment: Try: `/^(?:\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d{1,2})$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match optional digits followed by an optional dot and then match 1-2 digits.

```
^\d*\.?\d{1,2}$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\d*` Match 0+ digits
- `\.?` Match an optional `.`
- `\d{1,2}` Match 1-2 digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g2MSeO/1)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `+` by `*`

`+` : 1 or more, `*` : 0 or more

```
if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/", $weight))
```